# How to Sum Calculated Fields with VBA on MS Access Report

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, calculated-field

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here and hoping I explain this clearly enough. I'm getting undesirable results with my report because I need to sum calculated fields.  The Employee Name in the Employee ID header, the labels in the Week header and the Dates and Calculated Hours in the Details header are all showing correctly.  However, Access is filling in the information in the wrong order.

Here is what it is doing:

Calculating and filling in the hours for last day of the last week of the period ->

Filling in the hours for the last week of the period ->

Filling in the hours for the period ->

Calculating and filling in the last day for the previous week of the period ->

Filling in the hours for the previous week of the period ->

repeating until the first week.

Then filling in the rest of the calculated hours.

So My results show up like this: (Please note rounding is intentional and the reason I can't just do a =Sum([Hours]) in the footers)

```
Employee Name
    Date       Hours    Reg     OT
    9/8/15      8:00
    9/9/15      8:28
    9/10/15     8:00
    9/11/15     7:32 <--Inputs this fourth
    ------------------------------
Week Totals:    7:30   7:30   0:00 <--Inputs this fifth then fills in other dates

    Date       Hours    Reg     OT
    9/14/15     9:43
    9/15/15     8:00
    9/16/15    13:14
    9/17/15    11:39
    9/18/15     5:25 <--Starts here first
    ------------------------------
Week Totals:    5:30   5:30   0:00 <--Inputs this second
    ------------------------------
Period Totals:  5:30   5:30   0:00 <--Inputs this third
```

Here is how I have my report setup right now:

```
Employee Name                                                        (Employee ID Header)
Date       Hours                Regular            Overtime          (Week Header)
=[Date]    =CalcHours([Hours])                                       (Details)    
           =GetWeekTot()        =GetWeekReg()      =GetWeekOT()      (Week Footer)
           =GetPeriodTot()      =GetPeriodReg()    =GetPeriodOT()    (Employee ID Footer)
```

Here is my Module:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private WeekTot As Double
Private WeekReg As Double
Private WeekOT As Double

Private PeriodTot As Double
Private PeriodReg As Double
Private PeriodOT As Double

Public Function CalcHours(ByVal Hours As Double) As String
    'Add the Daily Hours to the Total Weekly Hours
    WeekTot = WeekTot + Hours

    'Format and Return the Daily Hours
    CalcHours = Int(Hours) & ":" & Format((Hours * 60) Mod 60, "00")
End Function

Public Function GetWeekTot() As String
    'Round the Total Weekly Hours to the Nearest Quarter Hour
    WeekTot = Round(WeekTot * 4, 0) / 4

    'Calculate the Regular Weekly Hours and the Overtime Weekly Hours
    If WeekTot > 40 Then
        WeekReg = 40
        WeekOT = WeekTot - 40
    Else
        WeekReg = WeekTot
        WeekOT = 0
    End If

    'Add the Total Weekly Hours to the Total Period Hours
    PeriodTot = PeriodTot + WeekTot

    'Format and Return the Total Weekly Hours
    GetWeekTot = Int(WeekTot) & ":" & Format(WeekTot * 60 Mod 60, "00")

    'Reset the Total Weekly Hours
    WeekTot = 0
End Function

Public Function GetWeekReg() As String
    'Add the Regular Weekly Hours to the Regular Period Hours
    PeriodReg = PeriodReg + WeekReg

    'Format and Return the Regular Weekly Hours
    GetWeekReg = Int(WeekReg) & ":" & Format(WeekReg * 60 Mod 60, "00")

    'Reset the Regular Weekly Hours
    WeekReg = 0
End Function

Public Function GetWeekOT() As String
    'Add the Overtime Weekly Hours to the Overtime Period Hours
    PeriodOT = PeriodOT + WeekOT

    'Format and Return the Overtime Weekly Hours
    GetWeekOT = Int(WeekOT) & ":" & Format(WeekOT * 60 Mod 60, "00")

    'Reset the Overtime Weekly Hours
    WeekOT = 0
End Function

Public Function GetPeriodTot() As String
    'Format and Return Total Period Hours
    GetPeriodTot = Int(PeriodTot) & ":" & Format((PeriodTot * 60) Mod 60, "00")

    'Reset the Total Period Hours
    PeriodTot = 0
End Function

Public Function GetPeriodReg() As String
    'Format and Return Total Period Hours
    GetPeriodReg = Int(PeriodReg) & ":" & Format((PeriodReg * 60) Mod 60, "00")

    'Reset the Total Period Hours
    PeriodReg = 0
End Function

Public Function GetPeriodOT() As String
    'Format and Return Total Period Hours
    GetPeriodOT = Int(PeriodOT) & ":" & Format((PeriodOT * 60) Mod 60, "00")

    'Reset the Total Period Hours
    PeriodOT = 0
End Function
```

If anyone could figure out a way to make it show this I would be greatly appreciative:

```
Employee Name
    Date       Hours    Reg     OT
    9/8/15      8:00
    9/9/15      8:28
    9/10/15     8:00
    9/11/15     7:32
    ------------------------------
Week Totals:   32:00  32:00   0:00 

    Date       Hours    Reg     OT
    9/14/15     9:43
    9/15/15     8:00
    9/16/15    13:14
    9/17/15    11:39
    9/18/15     5:25 
    ------------------------------
Week Totals:   48:00  40:00   8:00 
    ------------------------------
Period Totals: 80:00  72:00   8:00
```

Comment: Your calculation code is okay. Is there any code where these functions are called? Saying, that you can not use the footer because of rounding: Have you considered to add the round function to the footer expression?

Comment: @asdev The functions are only called in the textboxes of the report.  Everything executes OK with no execution errors.  At first I was just using the following Access expressions to calculate the Daily Hours: =Int([Hours]) & ":" & Format([Hours]*60 Mod 60,"00")    and Weekly and Period Hours were:   =Int(Round(Sum([Hours])*4,0)/4) & ":" & Format((Round(Sum([Hours])*4,0)/4)*60 Mod 60,"00").  However; that brought up the situation where the actual weekly hours could be 40:07 & 40:07 which would both be rounded to 40:00 each, but the period total would round to 80:15, which would not be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you revealed that the functions are called in the textboxes of the report let it be said that you can never be sure in what order Access calles them when the report is initialized.

I propose two other possibilities:

**1. Use Expression with extra Field**

Set in your report detail row a field of the real daily hour, name it e.g. DAILY_CORRECT_FIELD, an hide it by  visible set to false. Insert another text field, name it e.g. DAILY_ROUNDED_FIELD, where you insert the round-to-quarter expression. On the sum field for the week, refer sum(DAILY_CORRECT_FIELD), the invisible field with the unrounded value.

**2. Code based**

If you want to use VBA, do not write a module where you sum all the fields, especially when you do not have control in which order the function are called. Write a query instead where you sum up a week and set that to the field on the report. There are tons of tutorial on the web, so I will not explain this further.

Although being a big fan of using VBA, I would highly recommend suggestion 1, because of its simple implementation.

Comment: Lol didn't see this post until after I came up with a solution, but your 2nd solution would have also led me to where I ultimately ended up.  However; I did it without using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, @asdev, you made me think about using the access expressions again, but this time I added a sort of bypass aggregate query to group by the employee and the week, then rounded the sum in that query to give me the same totals as I would get in the week footers of my report. I then used the DSum function to filter the bypass query by Employee ID and sum the totals in my Period footer, giving me the correct totals.